# where to write the logic for checking element exists in Page object pattern using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, design-patterns, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have two packages,one which represent class/classes for test and while other is for page object.

Inside  the test class,I wanted to develop a logic where if a element is present i.e say a dropdown then follow one path and if not then follow another and then verify the results

While I see that page object pattern  will be used to interact with the elements on the page then where should the logic for test go which is again dependent on the web element (dropdwwn present or not).

If we start checking the element is present or not in the test class and then pass the driver object to Page object class then wouldnt it be duplication of work.

I am not sure what should be correct approach for designing when the logic is based on whether certain webelements are present on webpage or not.

Thanks.

Comment: I really don't think that it's a good approach. You **should** know in which case the element is present. But if it's the only way, I'd suggest to make logic in test class, and ,depending on result, call the method you need

Comment: I think its better to create methods in your page class to perform an action with a webelement. In this way you can identify if the element is present before performing the action and if present only then perform the action else throw exception.

Answer (score 1):

Write a separate class, say UTIL to hold these logic's. Also make use of this UTIL class for all your test data generation and error code handling.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to do something like:

```
try{
    element.isDisplayed();
    return true;
} catch(ElementNotFoundException e){
    return false;
}
```

I've found two places for this code:

The first is in your page class that all of your pages inherit.  If you don't have such a class, then a Utils class will work.  Your function call will then look something like `page.exists(page.getSaveButton())`.

However, my favorite way (that will require a little more setup), is to write a wrapper class around WebElement (I call it EnhancedWebElement).  It's constructor accepts a normal WebElement, and it redirects each function call to the WebElement, and has an exists() function.

Finally, to make every element have the exists() function, you will need to extend DefaultFieldDecorator, and override these functions:

```
@Override
public Object decorate(ClassLoader loader, Field field) {
  if (!(WebElement.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
      || isDecoratableList(field))) {
    return null;
  }

  ElementLocator locator = factory.createLocator(field);
  if (locator == null) {
    return null;
  }

  if (EnhancedWebElement.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
    return proxyForLocator(loader, locator);
  } else if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
    return proxyForListLocator(loader, locator);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
@Override
protected EnhancedWebElement proxyForLocator(ClassLoader loader, ElementLocator locator) {
  InvocationHandler handler = new LocatingElementHandler(locator);

  WebElement proxy= (WebElement) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    loader, new Class[] {WebElement.class, WrapsElement.class, Locatable.class}, handler);

  return new EnhancedWebElement(proxy);
}
```

To implement it, wherever you call initElements, call this:

```
PageFactory.initElements(new EnhancedFieldDecorator(new DefaultElementLocatorFactory(driver)), this);
//Replace EnhancedFieldDecorator with the name of your decorator
```

This may be more than you are asking for, and if it is, that top function is what you are looking for.